# How to subtract day from months?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to subtract **last day** from **this.maxIntervalDurationInMonts** ?

```
 private customIntervalDisable(startDate: string, amount: string, method: string): boolean {
    return this.maxIntervalDurationInMonths !== null
        ? moment()[amount](this.maxIntervalDurationInMonths, 'month')[method](startDate)
        : false;
}
```

Comment: @BenFortune What ?

Comment: **The OP is using moment.js**. just check the true part of the ternary operator: `? moment()[amount]...`

Answer (score 0):

Add ".subtract(1, 'day')" on this: (this.maxIntervalDurationInMonths, 'month')